# Extracting Key value pair in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, key-value

**I have json like below:**

```
{
  "values" :[
  {
    "cor": "1234567",
    "num": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "cor": "45676677",
    "num": "1234567890"
  },
  {
    "cor": "67899909",
    "num": "1235467898"
  }
]
}
```

**I need output like below:**

```
{ "values" :[ { "cor": "1234567", "num": "123456789" }]}
{ "values" :[ { "cor": "45676677", "num": "1234567890" }]}
{ "values" :[ { "cor": "67899909", "num": "1235467898" }]}
```

I can able to extract the keys and values separately but not able to create the json in the above json format I need. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Few code I have used to extract key value pair:

```
for key in data.keys():
    print(key);
for value in data.values():
    print(value);
for item in data["values"]:
    print(item);
```

Comment: The mentioned output is not actually a valid JSON unless it's a list of dictionaries. Ex: `[{ "values" :[ { "cor": "1234567", "num": "123456789" }]},{ "values" :[ { "cor": "45676677", "num": "1234567890" }]}, { "values" :[ { "cor": "67899909", "num": "1235467898" }]}]`. Do you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a list of the output that you're looking for

```
result = []
for value in data['values']:
    result.append({'values': [value]})
```

Output:

```
[{'values': [{'cor': '1234567', 'num': '123456789'}]}, {'values': [{'cor': '45676677', 'num': '1234567890'}]}, {'values': [{'cor': '67899909', 'num': '1235467898'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "output", you mean printing to the console, there's this code:

```
for item in my_json["values"]:
    print ({"values":[item]})
```

As a list, it would be `my_list = [{'values':[value]}) for value in my_json['values']]`, but that doesn't match the formatting you give.

If you want a string, you can do `my_string = '/n'.join(str({'values':[value]}) for value in my_json['values'])`

The default in Python is to print quotes as single quotes, so if you really want double quotes you'll have to do some string formatting, such as `my_string.replace('\'','"')`

The syntax for the replace is a bit confusing because you have to enclose the string that you're replacing in quote marks, but the quote marks are what you're trying to replace, so you have to do something complicated such as escaping the quote marks or using docstring quote demarcations.

Comment: This is the information I'm exactly looking for. I was almost there missed a minor part. Thanks for the help.